# How would I make something like puush

Tags: php

So I have my own webserver now and am hosting a website. I have made a basic screenshot to FTP. It copies the link once uploaded and I'm going to be adding randomized folders e.g /push/eqw8/woeqwe.jpg like puush does.

However, this is not my question. I was wondering how I would be able to grab all folders and images from those folders and create a table like this http://puu.sh/oEyfP/783483492c.png or http://puush.me/account in order from upload date. And then it shows in oderder of date uploaded.

I just wanted to do this because I feel more secure and its a fun project doing it.

How would I get about making this.

can you tell me like what I need to do in words?

I'm not good with web development and only good with languages like c# and such.

Learning php and html atm and its pretty basic but I still need time to learn.

Comment: All the haters lol. Guess I won't be getting any help here. 

Time to start reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first it depends on your php skills about how much you can think / do in php.

The main thing you need here to order the files / folders by date or manage them at much professional level , you have to use **Mysql** database and store Files and Folders information inside the database.

For example , **let say you have a Image file extension .jpeg** then store it's information about :

`Extension`  `File size`  `Parent Folder` `Uploader id / IP`  `Upload Date`   `Unique random key` `mime type` `Random name` `Original name`

And there are many other things you need to consider

- Files that are being stored by users should be scanned and non executable from the browser.
- Store them in random folders with random names so no body can find the way to the file.

You can use javascript/ ajax for uploading multiple files at the same time.

You can make the files non executable by removing their extensions and saving them inside a folder without their original names and  save their original names and extensions inside the database along with random string name and the folder name where it was stored so your system can identify the file and you can show your users the file and then on download you can replace the name with original one along with extension.

this is a one of my projects i have created , if you want you can check it out: [Buckty](https://buckty.com)

About any other information you need , you can ask me below in comment.

Comment: Thank you!

I will check it out after I finish with my Visualizer for my website ;P